# What does my tattoo mean?

Tags: meaning, character-identification

[image]

Sorry if my question is inappropriate, but I really need to know what this tattoo means. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You had a tattoo but you don't know what it means.... how could you?

Comment: Long story, I was 15 and the world was mine. Please tell me even if it's extreme stupid.

Comment: 乔基 (adjective + noun) apparently not a standard single word, characters and their meaning can be looked up in dictionaries

Comment: 乔基 /Qiáo jī/ sounds like a transliteration of English name

Comment: is your name George?

Comment: see e.g. iciba: 乔吉 variant of 乔基, 乔吉 second character with 2nd tone instead of 1st 
Georgie
[ˈdʒɔ:dʒi]

    n.

    George 的昵称；

    释义

    [男子名] 乔吉 George的昵称； [女子名] 乔吉 Georgia的昵称；

Answer (score 2):

乔基, I'm 95% sure it's transliteration for the name George. Also it looks a little bit odd to me since usually the transliteration would written as 乔治, at least in Mainland China. And that's a boy's name.

Comment: why not Georgie (Georgia的昵称)? (See comment #6)?

Comment: Thank you very much, this tattoo really was meant to be George. 2 days ago in a company somebody asked me what does it mean and when I said George, they laughed and made fun of it, saying it couldn't be George because it's not a chinese name at all. This made me doubt too after all these years and thats why I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

It is a transliteration of your name, and 乔生 is my Chinese (first) name. Although I am a guy, so this may go to 神秘德里克's point.

Answer (score 0):

In the old Chinese meaning, this meaning "I am a high-level man".